# Multiple commands in if statements throwing error

Tags: php, if-statement, printing

Im having trouble with some PHP code with multiple commands following a if statement. I have terminated each command with a semi-colon however php throws the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /test/process.php on line 18
```

referencing line 4 of this snippet:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($duperaw) > 0)
{
print '<script type="text/javascript">';
print 'alert("'$img_id' is already in '$type'")';
print '</script>';
header("location: process.php?img_id=$img_id");
}
else
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO $type (data) VALUES('$data')");
print '<script type="text/javascript">';
print 'alert("'$img_id' successfully added to '$type'")';
print '</script>';
}
```

The code works fine with one line in each {} however I thought the function of the {} was to allow multiple commands to be run within each if statement. I might just be overlooking something very simple as im still fairly new to php. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the full stops to join the strings:

so

```
print 'alert("'$img_id' is already in '$type'")';
```

becomes

```
print 'alert("'.$img_id.' is already in '.$type.'")';
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple. Thank you very much! I think I need to lower the resolution on this monitor :/